# React/TypeScript : Make a component interface with certain props, so that its parent can supply such props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a `MenuButton` interface or type which is supposed to have a "isMenuOpen" prop, that its parent can supply.

```
function Menu({ SomeButton }: { SomeButton: MenuButton }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return <div><SomeButton isMenuOpen={isOpen} />{ isMenuOpen ? menu stuff : null }</div>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understood correctly, you mean something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-neytag?file=index.tsx

Comment: I actually want to style the menu button depending on the isMenuOpen prop. So the gist is that the button needs to accept the property isMenuOpen.

Comment: So, you want to be able to pass any react component compatible with props `{ isMenuOpen: boolean }`?

Comment: Exactly @tokland

Comment: I updated my stackblitz if you want to take a look

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for @coglialoro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type [React.ComponentType](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L82):

```
type MenuProps = { SomeButton: React.ComponentType<{ isOpen: boolean }> }

function Menu(props: MenuProps) {
    return <SomeButton isOpen={true} />
}
```

Comment: Yes I was confused at first to be honest, but looking at @coglialoro code example I realized that it does answer the question.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that first one entirely :) Still though, I think `React.ComponentType` is preferred here since it could be a class or functional component. What maters are the props.